# Featured Image on wordpress - get default image rather than 500x500

Tags: css, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

My site was showing thumbnails at 16:9 ratio. Old posts are still showing at 16:9. Old posts are using the default image that is xyz.jpg but now whenever I create a new post and set an image as Featured image it is showing square image instead of 16:9 aspect. it brings a image of size 500x500 and the name of the file will be xyz-500x500.jpg is there a way I can make featured image shown is xyz.jpg rather than xyz-500x500.jpg?

My site is http://cookingshooking.in

Just background:
I ported my site from different theme to [Lobster](http://wordpress.org/themes/lobster) three days back, I used plugin called Media tools to set featured for all the previous posts. It assigned all the first image of the post as featured image. I am not sure does this plugin has to do with setting the size of the thumbnail.

Please help all I need is featured/thumbanil image on front page should take default image which I upload that is xyz.jpg rather than xyz-500x500.jpg  I do not want to hard code the size for thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

i have not installed the lobster theme anywhere, but a quick search shows that there are only two locations where lobster is getting the_post_thumbnail.

once in content.php and once in content-image.php

you can add a [custom image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in functions.php,
then use this imagesize instead of large in line 17 of content-image.php

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'your-image-size-name', array( 'class' => 'alignnone img-polaroid' ) );
```

Alternatively you can change the pixel sizes of the "large" size in the wordpress settings->media admin page,
or use "medium" if you need large somewhere else and set the medium size in the settings->media area.

Comment: Thank you for your input, But this is what I didn't wanted to do, that is edit functions.php as you can see my other posts are using the default image as I said xyz.jpg but the latest post is using xyz-500x500.jpg this I got to know when I did Inspect element.

Comment: well, other than changing the large size through the media admin like i explained above there wont be a way to change them then, changing the large sizes should work though.

Comment: Now I have set Large size to 600 from 1024,  and medium as it is 300. lets me check how the image will be shown after this settings change. I will update you whats the result

Comment: to make sure your thumbs are resized properly you can use this:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

and you want to set the large size to the actual size you use in the page, otherwise you load unnecessarily large images